# How to delete from string particular word containing double quotes ''"?

Tags: php, double-quotes

I want to delete    `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`  from my string containg this and after that lots of other things. How to delete it because of several double quotes I am having problem to define `str_replace` function.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please.

Comment: I tried str_replace("<?xml version='"1.0"' encoding='"utf-8"'?>", '', $myString); dont know why you gave mi minus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider using single quotes:

```
str_replace('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>', '', $myString);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use single quotes then with str_replace :

```
$yourstring = str_replace('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>', '', $yourstring);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you *want* to use double quotes to define the string then you **need** to escape them with `\`:

```
str_replace("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>", "", $myString);
//                         ^    ^           ^      ^
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```
<?php

    $xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <parentnode>
                <childnode>
                    Hello World!
                </childnode>
            </parentnode>';

    $xml_to_delete = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>';

    $new_xml = str_replace($xml_to_delete, "", $xml);

    echo $new_xml; //Raw XML.

    echo "<br/>";

    echo htmlentities($new_xml); //For seeing output in browsers, instead of XML rendered.
```